# Confused on Querydsl extensions?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I was researching about Querydsl and landed on  [this](http://www.slideshare.net/timowestkamper/querydsl-fin-jug-june-2012)  slide. It has the coverage of almost all the information about querydsl that one should know. But on "Querydsl extensions" topic of the slide, it has the more information of Querydsl customization instead of extension. I am hugely confused over here. Can somebody explain me how those customizations can be regarded as extensions?

Comment: I am asking about the choice of terminology. I felt that the information you have provided on "Querydsl Extensions" topic of the slide is more about customization than extension. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizations might be a better choice in this case. Extension was chosen as the options can be considered extension points in the Querydsl code generation process. I don't see a huge difference in extension vs customization points.

Comment: Based on your view, i think i can say that "Querydsl can be extended by customizing provided query type and query". What do you think about that?

Comment: Or maybe the other way around? Querydsl queries and expressions can be customized via these extension points. English is not my first language so I might be totally wrong ;)